# How to count localStorage value in jQuery one by one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm working on this much more that I should have, but after days of testing it seems I can't find a way to achieve what I'm trying to do here.

I am making a image voting system, which will log votes in localStorage. This is in WordPress, so there is no really much of HTML there.

Here is the code, and I will try to explain each step briefly.

HTML:

```
[gallery link="none" size="medium" ids="102,13,27,25,23,15" orderby="rand"]

<div class="exists" style="display:none;">Thank you for voting!</div>
```

The class `.exists` with HTML is to be shown when the jQuery criteria is met.

CSS:

```
.gallery-item a {
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    border-radius: 6px;
    color: orange;
    display: inline-table;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 32%;
}  
.exists {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 18px;
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 20px -3px grey inset;
    display: block;
    height: 32%;
    left: 24%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 12%;
    padding-top: 6%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 23%;
    width: 36%;
    z-index: 999999;
    color: olivedrab;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: context-menu;
}
.voted {
    background-color: green !important;
}
```

This is clear, I believe.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var voteLink = $('.gallery-item a');
    var votedYes = $('.exists');
        voteLink.on('click', function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            localStorage.setItem('voted1', 'yes1');
            $(this).text('Thank you!');
            $(this).addClass('voted');
            })
        });
$(document).ready(function() {
    var voteLink = $('.gallery-item a');
    var votedYes = $('.exists');
        voteLink.on('click', function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            localStorage.setItem('voted2', 'yes2');
            $(this).text('Thank you!');
            $(this).addClass('voted');
            })
        });
$(document).ready(function() {
    var voteLink = $('.gallery-item a');
    var votedYes = $('.exists');
        voteLink.on('click', function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            localStorage.setItem('voted3', 'yes3');
            $(this).text('Thank you!');
            $(this).addClass('voted');
            voteLink.remove();
            $('.exists').show();
        });
        if (localStorage.getItem("voted3")) {
        voteLink.remove();
        votedYes.fadeIn(1800);
     } else {
    } 
});$(document).ready(function() {
    var voteLink = $('.gallery-item a');
    var votedYes = $('.exists');
        voteLink.on('click', function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            localStorage.setItem('voted1', 'yes1');
            $(this).text('Thank you!');
            $(this).addClass('voted');
            })
        });
$(document).ready(function() {
    var voteLink = $('.gallery-item a');
    var votedYes = $('.exists');
        voteLink.on('click', function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            localStorage.setItem('voted2', 'yes2');
            $(this).text('Thank you!');
            $(this).addClass('voted');
            })
        });
$(document).ready(function() {
    var voteLink = $('.gallery-item a');
    var votedYes = $('.exists');
        voteLink.on('click', function() {
            event.preventDefault();
            localStorage.setItem('voted3', 'yes3');
            $(this).text('Thank you!');
            $(this).addClass('voted');
            voteLink.remove();
            $('.exists').show();
        });
        if (localStorage.getItem("voted3")) {
        voteLink.remove();
        votedYes.fadeIn(1800);
     } else {
    } 
});
```

What happens here, on first click all votes are logged in localStorage (voted1, voted2 and voted3) and then because the "voted3" is triggered the logic continues as it shouldn't have. How do I prevent this? How to make that value is stored only on click?

Thank you very much.

Comment: There's a whole bunch of events firing when the user clicks on .gallery-item a... Is this your actual code or did you paste the same code multiple times? Or - very possible - do I misunderstand the code?

Comment: It's the actual code..

Comment: I need it to stick with only one event, how do I do this?

Comment: what exactly do you want to accomplish with your code?

Comment: From your targeting I am assuming that the WordPress plugin creates three buttons that the user can click on. If that is correct, you will need to properly target each of those buttons - and not a generic anchor element. Also, you will want to pickup the ID or name of the image that the user voted for, but it seems you need to fix the first challenge first.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (localStorage.getItem("voted3") == "yes3") {
        voteLink.remove();
        votedYes.fadeIn(1800);
      localStorage.setItem("voted3","removel")
}
```

Comment: Could you please take a look at my code again? Thanks